# Rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed error iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift5, inputaccessoryview

I have seen similar questions for this but not yet a good solution.

I am using a custom input accessory view to have an interactive keyboard/text field in my app to build something like the iMessage controller.

When dismissing the keyboard I get the error rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed.

Currently I'm using the library `InputBarAccessoryView` and am still getting the same rejection. Here is my full error warning

```
[View] First responder warning: '<InputBarAccessoryView.InputTextView: 0x7feb280b3e00; baseClass = UITextView; frame = (0 0; 330 38); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; tintColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.239216 0.67451 0.968627 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003239bf0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003dd4280>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {139, 36.5}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>' rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy
```

This warning also causes my `chatViewController` message cells to behave unexpectedly.

Any tips on what may be happening here will be very appreciated!

Comment: This also happens when im not using InputBarAccessoryView btw

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: I can post my custom input accessory view if that helps? I'm adding it to a UICollectiongView, im using the `.interactive` setting for my keyboard on the collectionView settings. I will post my view controller when I get home

Comment: You can post as much code as you can.